# Bundle assets with libGDX dependency

Tags: libgdx, dependencies, project-structure

I'm making a card game engine on top of libGDX for many similar games I plan to make. Here's how I plan to structure this: each game is a separate project and the engine is a dependency added to the `core` module. The engine itself will have a lot of assets like card sprites and other UI elements, and they need to be included too.

How can I make that structure work? Is there any way to make a dependency include its assets? The alternative is to duplicate all assets for each game which I don't think is very efficient. Also the assets are in the `android` module by default, which the engine dependency doesn't have (the engine is a single module). Where do I put the assets in the engine module?

Comment: Is your project a Gradle project created with the LibGDX Project Generator?

Comment: The engine project is just a single module, but the games the engine is included in are projects generated with the project generator. (both are Gradle based)

Comment: Looking at this page, I believe you might be able to store the images as a Classpath file.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

You only need them to be read only and they aren't game assets, they are part of your engine.

Comment: @Fooble Thanks, it looks like something that might work. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Another option would be to do away with including assets in the engine and have the engine import a Skin & Texture Atlas.
That way the elements could have the same names but vary from game to game.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#textureatlas

Comment: What do you mean by having the engine import a texture atlas? Would it be imported automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a setup that seems similar to what you've outlined above with a "many to one" relationship of projects to assets. Here's a potential way to go about it.

**The basic idea is:**

1. Have a single, authoritative assets folder
2. Have individual projects copy this folder to their build output at build time
3. Accomplish this by having a project's compile task `dependsOn` or be `finalizedBy` a copy task.
4. Ensure that the Android and other projects are happy by copying the assets to the place that libgdx's internal File APIs look for that particular type of project. (For example, android projects automatically get an `assets/` prepended to the URI provided to `Gdx.files.internal()`. This step is more dependent on your personal file structure, so it may take a little tweaking to get the pathing right for all projects, but don't get discouraged!

*Side-note: Gradle should automatically track whether or not the assets dir actually changed. If nothing's been updated, then the copy tasks will effectively become no-ops, which speeds up the build quite a bit for non-first runs. Obviously if you do a `cleanAssets` like I mention below, then this won't apply.*

The advantage of this approach (to me anyway) is that it no longer relies on cross-project links or funky classpath manipulation. It's just real files in real directories. The downside is that it increases the disk space used because there can be multiple physical copies of the assets in the various projects.

The following is not a complete example, but should hopefully give you enough to go by.

**Example of a copy task in action.** This particular one takes an assets dir from a "core" project and copies it into an android project.

```
android/build.gradle

task copyAssets(type: Copy) {
    from "../core/assets"
    into "./assets"
}
```

**Example of how to make the android project's build depend on this task:**

```
android/build.gradle

afterEvaluate { project ->
    project.tasks.preDebugBuild {
        dependsOn copyAssets
    }

    project.tasks.preReleaseBuild {
        dependsOn cleanAssets
        finalizedBy copyAssets
    }
}
```

You'll notice in the preReleaseBuild I added a `cleanAssets` task as well. It's always a good idea to clean up any junk and do a fresh copy during a production build. `cleanAssets` is just a basic Delete task.

**Example of a copy task dependency for a non-android project:**

```
build {
    finalizedBy copyAssets
}
```

If you're still stuck, let me know where and I'll try to help.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! I only had to change `copyAssets` to `":android:copyAssets"` in the desktop build.gradle since gradle couldn't find the task. When packing my game to an APK or JAR file, will there be any additional steps or everything will be the same?

Comment: Nice! If you want to avoid that cross project reference, you could make a second copyAssets build task specific to the desktop project, but that's totally up to you. If you talk to the Gradle gurus, they'll recommend against explicitly referencing one project's task from another, but spoiler: we do it too in ours, haha.

Comment: The great part about having the copy as part of the build task is that any task that depends on the "build" now also by extension depends on the copyAssets task. So given a default jar build or apk build, you'll hit "build" and/or preReleaseBuild task during the deploy automatically. You can actually verify it from the command line if you use gradle or gradlew by doing a dry run and ensuring you see copyAssets in the command output.
Something like: `./gradlew --dry-run :android:assembleRelease`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like libgdx does itself. There are assets included in the classpath, like arial-15.fnt which is located in the core project at gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/. Take a look at `BitmapFont`'s no-param constructor how it is referenced.

Comment: Will that also work on Android since the assets are not in the assets folder?

Comment: [FileHandle documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Files.FileType.html#Classpath) says sound and music cannot be classpath files on Android, which will be a problem for me. Any way around that?

Comment: We had a big push to move our assets folder to be a peer to our sub projects, which is somewhat related to what you're wanting to do. What we did was to add a gradle task that copies whatever we need assets-wise over to the android project at build time. You can accomplish this by specifying that the android build task either "dependsOn" or is "finalizedBy" your custom copy task. This uses more disk space, but allows the core assets folder to remain the authoritative source for assets across multiple projects.

Comment: @Harvtronix I think this is a better option, but I couldn't make it work. Does the task need to be in the android module or the core module since desktop also needs it? What path do you copy the files to? What do you specify as a working directory for the desktop configuration? It would help a lot if you could provide the gradle task if that's possible.